# Trouble with AJAX Load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

I'm new to jQuery, and am starting off with an AJAX load function, for some reason, I can't get it to work, I have tried many different forms (using .php etc) and eventually adopted the first one I tried. I'm loading my content from a separate .html file and using individual divs from within this file as anchor points for the AJAX to insert into my main content div.

Head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="core.js"></script>
```

Navigation:

```
<div id="leftnav">
    <p class="leftnavtext">
        <a class="navlinks" id="about2" href="#">ABOUT</a> <br>
        <a class="navlinks" id="process2" href="#">PROCESS</a> <br>
    </p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $("about2").click(function(){
    $("#content").load("content.html #about");
  });
});
```

The div I aim to load it into is obviously `#content` and currently I am only trying this method out with a single link to try and get it to work.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: is that a typo by chance? `about2` should be `#about2`

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo, but it hasn't made the function work at all.

Answer (score 0):

load is just a wrapper for AJAX, so you can instead do this inside of your click function...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "content.html"})
    .done(function(data) {
      var $about = $(data).filter("#leftnav").children('#about2').html();       
      console.log($about);
      $('#content').html($about);
    });
});
```

You're filtering your way down to a specific ID from within your external file.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but replacing load function with this post function doesn't seem to do the trick either. I'm wondering if the issue lies within the links having both a class and an id.

Comment: what message are you getting the console?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/student/Desktop/CROOKED%20CARTOON/Website/content.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. print2.html:1

Any use?

Comment: Uploading it to a server should fix it then?